# WPF - Not working IsReadOnly in DataGrid with custom CheckBox style

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I currently have a custom CheckBox style which I use in a DataGrid. However, when I specify the IsReadOnly="true" property in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn, this is no longer working (can I still click and change the value of the CheckBox). I also used Expression Blend to extract a copy of the original WPF style, and this one has the same problem. Only the original CheckBox style seems to be working, which I don't want.

I currently manage to solve it by creating a new style based on my normal one with the IsHitTestVisible and Focusable properties on false, but I want the IsReadOnly property from the DataGridCheckBoxColumn to work without this workaround.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Not a bad work around.  Maybe try a DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: Thanks Blam, I tried DataGridTemplateColumn and encountered the same problem. Does anyone know what the IsReadOnly property is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is your case: try to set somewhere in the style this xaml:

```
IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding}"
```

or

```
IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, but a checkbox does not have an IsReadOnly property. Any other solutions?

Comment: According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.issealed.aspx) article, `IsSealed` property should be what you really needs

Comment: I know about IsSealed, but it's set internally, and cannot be modified as stated on MSDN: Gets a value that indicates whether this instance is currently sealed (read-only). + This value is set internally.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "IsEnabled" on CheckBox (should be on all other controls, I think) can do the job.